# Calculating the Lines of Code Estimate for a PHP, MySQL, HTML web app from Function Points

Tags: php, html, mysql, lines-of-code, function-points

We need to convert our Function Point estimation to a Lines of Code estimation for our web application, which uses HTML5, PHP, MySQL and CSS3.

The total number of function points we ended up with was 1727.24. What would be the best approach? All we can find are ways to convert client side software (eg C++, Perl programs etc) function point estimations to LOC applications.

Even a link to a helpful website would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some values on these sites

http://www.qsm.com/resources/function-point-languages-table

~34 LOC/FP for HTML
~47 LOC/FP for JS
~21 LOC/FP for SQL

https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/taina/ohtu/fp.html

~67 LOC/FP for PHP